# Incorrect Syntax near 'order' when using the Min aggreate function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm need to run the following query in `SQL Server 2008R2` but it's throwing me the error `Incorrect Syntax near 'Order'` on Min/Max aggregate part of the query.

Note that the PONumber field is a string but we use the `min/max` to identify the first and last po and this `works as expected` in `2012`.

Anyway this can be resolved?

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber,
        RN_ASC  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID 
                                     ORDER BY PoNumber ASC),
        RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID 
                                     ORDER BY PoNumber DESC),
        CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID),
        F = MIN(PONumber) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId 
                                ORDER BY PoNumber ASC),
        L = MAX(PONumber) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId 
                                ORDER BY PoNumber ASC)
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE (PONumber IS NOT NULL) AND (PONumber <> '') AND 
          (DocumentType = 'Purchase Order') and docmasterid > 0
)
```

Comment: is this the full query?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 does not support cumulative `min()`, `max()`, `avg()`, or `sum()`.  You can always upgrade to SQL Server 2012, which does.

Comment: Yes it is for the querying part but we've in our actual query to do inserts into temp tables and update an another table.

Comment: Upgrading is not an option I'm afraid. Client will not go for it. Is there any work-around to achieve the same results?

Comment: Why do you need ORDER in MAX() OVER()?

Comment: An order by clause in a subquery is at best, useless, and is probably causing your error.

Comment: Using the Min/Max allowed us to returned the first & last POnumber for records that have the same DocMasterId but different PONumber.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is strange.  You are taking the cumulative min and max of a column, which is the column used for the ordering.  So:

- The min is the overall min (for each `DocMasterId`).  A cumulative min is not needed.
- The max is the current value (for each `DocMasterId`), which also happens to be the current value period.  A cumulative max is not needed.

So, you can rewrite the logic as:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber,
        RN_ASC  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID 
                                     ORDER BY PoNumber ASC),
        RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID 
                                     ORDER BY PoNumber DESC),
        CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID),
        F = MIN(PONumber) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId)
        L = PoNumber
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE (PONumber IS NOT NULL) AND (PONumber <> '') AND 
          (DocumentType = 'Purchase Order') and docmasterid > 0
)
```

You might actually want:

```
        F = MIN(PONumber) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId)
        L = PoNumber OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId)
```

But the first query is equivalent to the query in your question (well, if the `PoNumber` could be `NULL`, I'd have to think harder about whether they are exactly equivalent in that case).

Comment: Thanks Gordon... As strange as the logic may be, the results are correct in 2012. We've actually found a work-around but that's not an answer to the question so I'm not sure how to close this now?? We did end up using the F=Min & L=Max on our AuditId instead and we then re-queried CTE using a join to get the relevant PONumber associated with the Min AuditId and the Max AuditId.

Comment: If we just used the `PartitionBy`, we had no way to ensure that the First PoNumber was actually the first one associated with a given DocMasterId. Same for the Last PoNumber, so using the Order By resolved that for us in SQL 2012.

Comment: @Thierry . . . Your comment makes no sense.  `MIN(PoNumber)` and `ORDER BY PoNumber` will both return the minimum `PoNumber` (when there are no `NULL` values).  Perhaps the query in your question doesn't actually represent your real query.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement using subqueries should be equivalent:

```
WITH myCTE(AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber) AS
(
    SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE (PONumber IS NOT NULL) AND (PONumber <> '') AND 
          (DocumentType = 'Purchase Order') and docmasterid > 0
),
CTE AS
(
SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID 
                          ORDER BY PoNumber ASC) AS RN_ASC,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID 
                          ORDER BY PoNumber DESC) AS RN_DESC,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myCTE t2 WHERE t2.DocMasterID = t.DocMasterID) AS CNT,
       ( SELECT MIN(PONumber) FROM myCTE  t2 WHERE t2.DocMasterID = t.DocMasterID) AS  F,
       ( SELECT MAX(PONumber) FROM myCTE  t2 WHERE t2.DocMasterID = t.DocMasterID) AS L
FROM myCTE t
)
```

Comment: Even though we found a work-around, I was interested in your solution but I can't get it to run in SQL 2008R2. I'm getting the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near (' at line 19, which is the last ')'. I've checked the brackets and can't see any missing ones. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we ended up using as a work-around. Unfortunately, anyone trying to help wouldn't have been able to provide the final answer as we ended up using another field in our Query i.e. `AuditId`. Note this field was not required in `SQL Server 2012`.

Using the `AuditId` field allowed us to use the Min/Max aggregate function and using the `Partion By` as part of our query without using the `Order By`.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AuditId, DocMasterId, PoNumber,
           RN_ASC  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY DocMasterID ORDER BY AuditId ASC),
           RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY DocMasterID ORDER BY AuditId DESC),
           CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterID),
           MIN(AuditId) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId) AS F,
           MAX(AuditId) OVER (PARTITION BY DocMasterId) AS L
     FROM MyTable
     WHERE (PONumber IS NOT NULL) AND (PONumber <> '') AND 
     (DocumentType = 'Purchase Order') and docmasterid > 0
)
```

We then applied a couple of `inner join` to return the PONumber associated with the AuditId.

The returned results from our audit table were then used to fix the erroneous entries in our live table, so it was it was critical for us the ensure the FirstPO and LastPO were indeed in the correct order in our audit table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CTE.DocMasterId, A.PONumber AS FirstPO, B.PONumber AS LastPO
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN MyTable A 
  ON CTE.F = A.AuditId  
INNER JOIN MyTable B 
  ON CTE.L = B.AuditId  
WHERE CNT >= 2 and a.PONumber <> B.PONumber
AND (RN_ASC = 1 OR RN_DESC = 1) AND (F <> L)
ORDER BY CTE.DocMasterId;
```

Thanks again to all for trying to help. Really appreciated.